# How to load properties from kubernetes configMap based on activated spring profiles

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, spring-cloud-config, fabric8

Using helm I am setting the SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE as a dev or prod based on the environment. But now I want to load properties from kubernetes configMap based on the activated profile.

Below is the sample configMap

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  application-dev.properties: |-
    spring.profiles=dev
    host=hello-dev
  application-prod.properties: |-
    spring.profiles=prod
    host=hello-prod
  application.properties: |-
    host: hello-app
kind: ConfigMap
```

I am using io.fabric8 kubernetes dependency to use configMap in order to replace the spring cloud config server.

Output of sample API to fetch host property always gives the values as "hello-app" even though dev profile is activated.

Please suggest any method of solving the issue.

Thanks

Comment: I had same requirements. You probably have custom script to dynamically create bootstrap.yaml on the air based on mounted config file.

Comment: There's now a spring cloud project based on the fabric8 spring cloud kubernetes. Within there you can find https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-kubernetes/blob/master/spring-cloud-kubernetes-config/src/test/resources/application-with-profiles.yaml I'm not sure the fabric8 version has the same support - see also https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-kubernetes/issues/106

Comment: Thanks Kane and Ryan, I switched to use spring-cloud-kubernetes which has the support to have multiple profiles in the configMaps. But for this to work I need to update my spring boot to 2.1.0 from 1.5.8

Comment: Hi @ravi: I am also facing the same issue. Spring boot is not picking up any profile other than the default application.properties from the configmap. If your issue is fixed, could u share any github for the example? Thx in advance.

Answer (score -1):

apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
data:
application.yaml: |-
host: hello-app
---
spring:
profiles: dev
host: hello-dev